# how to get real ip of server behind nginx

Tags: nginx

i use nginx for load banlancing ,there are several servers behind nginx.
how to konw the server which the request forward to ?
Can I add the ip of the server that request forward to into header of reponse?
if can ,how to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to nginx [manual upstream section](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUpstreamModule). $upstream_addr variable may be what you want.

And another method is to add trace code to the request. You can refer to this [3-rd module](https://github.com/kali/nginx-operationid).